# ¿Por que Webpack me da este error al compilar sass?

Tags: webpack

Uso múltiples loaders para los estilos, como `sass-loader`, `style-loader`, `less-loader`, `postcss-loader`, `css-loader` para compilar estilos `.scss` y la consola me da este error:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/style-loader/dist!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/main.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    CssSyntaxError

    (1:1) Unknown word

    > 1 | var content = require("!!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./main.scss");
        | ^
      2 | 
      3 | if (typeof content === 'string') {
```

La configuración de mi archivo webpack.config.prod.js es este:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(le|sc|sa|c)ss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCss.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'style-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                    'less-loader'
                ],

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea reglas separadas para cada fichero que tiene que ser procesado por loaders independientes (esto en caso de que estés trabajando con ficheros `css`, `sass` y `less` en tu proyecto a la vez, si solo usas ficheros `sass` añade solo una de las reglas):

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader' ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ]
    }
]
```

Ten en cuenta siempre que los loaders se leen en orden inverso, por lo que si vas a utilizar [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) y [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) juntos, debes poner `style-loader` primero y `css-loader` después.

Y si estás usando [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin), no es necesario que uses `style-loader`, ya que el primero es para extraer los estilos en ficheros externos y el segundo para inyectar los estilos en tu `HTML` final.